# Invoking higher order functions - Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Hi I am new to Scala and trying to call a higher order function sum_of from main class.I am getting "Cannot resolve reference sumOf with such signature error".

```
object SumOf {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val y =  sumOf(x=>x ,4,5)
    println(y)
  }

  def sumOf(f: Int => Int)(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    def loop(a: Int, acc: Int): Int =
      if (a > b) acc
      else loop(a + 1, f(a) + acc)
      loop(a, 0)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sumOf` method has two argument lists, and needs to be called with two argument lists.

```
val y = sumOf(x => x)(4, 5)
```

You can think of `sumOf` as a function which takes an `Int => Int` and returns a new function, which takes two Ints to return an Int.

Answer (score 2):

`sumOf` is a curried function so it takes two arguments in the form of `sumOf(x => x)(4,5)` which is different from `sumOf(x => x, 4,5)`. This is the reason you are getting an error.

Further, you can call it with only one argument `sumOf(x => x) _` which returns another function that takes the second argument 
`(Int, Int) => Int = <function2>` and return a function. This is more commonly known as partial function application.